# Google Charts Axis lines not getting

Tags: google-visualization

Presently i am using Google charts to show reports in my .net web application.I am using google combo charts,column charts.Here is the sample code i am using.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
         ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
         ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
         ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
         ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
         ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
      ]);

    var options = {
      title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
      vAxis: {title: 'Cups'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

When i execute this code i am geting horizontal grid lines,but i want one vertical grid line also starting from "0" position.I want Vertical Gridline like shown in below URL(image).How can i acheive it by using google visualization API.Your help wil appriciated...

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=500x300&chd=t:50,60,80,40,20,40,30&chxt=x,y&chxl=0%3a|A|B|C|D|E|F|G&chdl=A%3DStupidTest1|B%3DStupidTest2|C%3DStupidTest3|D%3DStupidTest4|E%3DStupidTest5|F%3DStupidTest6|G%3DStupidTest7

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solution that i am aware of, but both solution dictates the horizontal months values to be continuous - means it should be the data column type to one of: number, date, datetime or timeofday. Yours was type string for the month column.

Solution 1 - used numeric value for month you can use date and format it with hAxis:'some date format' and also used baseline:0

```html
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
         [1,  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
         [2,  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
         [3,  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
         [4,  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
         [5,  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
      ]);

    var options = {
      title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
      vAxis: {title: 'Cups', gridlines:{count:3}},
      hAxis: {title: 'Month', baseline:0},
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
    };
 
 
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Solution 2 - here also used numeric value for month but this time used ticks: [{v:0}]

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
         [1,  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
         [2,  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
         [3,  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
         [4,  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
         [5,  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
      ]);

    var options = {
      title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
      vAxis: {title: 'Cups', gridlines:{count:3}},
      hAxis: {title: 'Month', ticks: [{v:0}]},
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
    };
 
 
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: first of all thanx for your valuable reply.But the above code is just sample coe.I am retriving data from SQL server.In that i may get months as Jan,Feb,March...etc or i may get Grade1,Grade2,Grade3 values in 1st column.In that senario how can i get that vertical axis line to my chart.

Comment: Like I said, it is not possible for String values. You need to provide for example numeric values then may be use some formatting. Another work around is to draw the vertical axis yourself

Comment: You can use overlays to draw your own vertical line! If you give me proper example which you will be using, i can figure out the solution, until that, my answer is the right one!

Comment: Thanx CodeBusta for responding with your valuable answers.In first column of my result set string caolumn is coming from database,but i want a vertical axis line for my chart.Here the code and sample result set iam getting...

Comment: var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Grade', 'A', 'A+', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'],
         ['Grade1',  88,96, 77,  63,55,28],
         ['Grade2',  84,93,77,63, 31],
         ['Grade3',  81,97, 74, 64,22],
         ['Grade4',  89,99,72, 66,68,33],
      ]);

Comment: For this result set i want one vertical axis line starting from zero th position.I am using google combo chart.How can i achieve this?

Comment: I will come up with solution as soon as I have free time.